# "Uncaught ReferenceError: func is not defined"

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

I am answering a question on Stack Overflow and added some simple JavaScript code. I define a function, call the function once, and then setup an event listener on a button to also call the function. When the button is clicked, the following error is logged in the Result pane:

Error:  {
    "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: func is not defined",
    "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
    "lineno": 14,
    "colno": 61
  }

The offending JavaScript code is:

```
const btn = document.getElementById('sub');

const appendNewTextArea = function() {
  const formEl = document.getElementById('form');
  const textareaTemplate = document.getElementById('textarea-template').innerHTML;
  const wrapper = document.createElement('div');
  wrapper.innerHTML = textareaTemplate;
  formEl.appendChild(wrapper);
}


// Call the function to create the first textarea
appendNewTextArea();

btn.addEventListener('click',appendNewTextArea);
```

Is this an error in the code? Or in how the code is run on Stack Overflow?

Question on Stack overflow - *[Display textbox multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45648602/display-textbox-multiple-times/45648902#45648902)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your HTML markup you have this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn" id="sub" onclick="func()">Next</button>
```

That `onclick` calls `func()` and that function is nowhere to be found. The error is on your side, not an SE bug.

Comment: Argh, copy and paste got me again.